# How to plot a graph with weighted edges in R

Tags: r, igraph

```
library(igraph)
data <- read.csv("Desktop/SNA/Data/Sample.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
```

**The input as below**:

```
    V1  V2   V3
1    5   2 0.01
2    5 159 0.03
3    2 100 0.15
4    2 858 0.12
5    3 100 0.08
6    3 114 0.07
7    3 171 0.02
8    3 858 0.01
9    5 100 0.04
10 858   2 0.01
```

`V1` and `V2` are the vertices and `V3` is the weight of the link.

I want to plot a graph by considering `V3` as the weight for links between `V1` and `V2`. I will use the graph for other processing.

Comment: What have you tried? How is the weight to reflect on the graph? Length of the branch, line thickness?

Comment: You can read about plotting options in `?igraph.plotting`. You are looking for the `edge.weight` parameter, and you would set it to something like `E(g)$weight` (adjusted for the name of your graph and the attribute you've used to store the weights).